# Transpose DataFrame based on Column Name Defined Range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

So I have some server logs that i'm trying to parse into a tabular format.  Imagine the logs are structured like this

```
a = "value1"
b = "value2"
c = "value3"
a = "value4"
c = "value5"
a = "value2"
b = "value12"
c = "value8"
```

Where my definition of a 'record' (or row in my final DataFrame) are all of the columns from A to C.  In reality there are 30 or so columns, by the starting column name and ending column name are always the same.

I can very easily read this file into a list (using the split("=") function) and arrive at something like this:
index value

```
1 ['a , 'value1']
2 ['b , 'value2']
3 ['c , 'value3']
4 ['a , 'value4']
5 ['c , 'value5']
6 ['a , 'value2']
7 ['b , 'value12']
8 ['c , 'value8']
```

I can even convert that to a 1 record dataframe with something like:
df = pd.DataFrame(List).transpose()
but I arrive at a DataFrame where Columns are repeated
like

```
a          b       c       a1       c2     a3       b1        c3 
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value2, value12, value8
```

What I really want is something that looks like this:

```
A          B        C
Value1   Value2   Value3
Value4   NULL     Value5
Value2   Value12  Value8
```

Any thoughts how to perform that transpose step to tell it to insert a new record in the DataFrame every time it sees "c" and keep writing until the next time it sees a C, placing a NULL value where no record exists for a particular column?

Am i going about this entirely incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df[['a','b']] = df['col'].str.split('\s+=\s+', expand=True)

df = (df.set_index([df['a'].eq('a').cumsum(), 'a'])['b']
       .unstack()
       .rename_axis(None, 1)
       .rename_axis(None))
print (df)
          a          b         c
1  "value1"   "value2"  "value3"
2  "value4"       None  "value5"
3  "value2"  "value12"  "value8"
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['a'].eq('a').cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    3
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column `col` by regex `\s+=\s+` - `1 or more whitepaces with =`
2. Create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `Series` created by comparing start value `a` with [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)
3. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
4. Last data cleaning by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)